# ListView showing only one item or last item

Tags: android, listview, adapter

The title of this question is same but technical issue are different.

Hi i am trying to get data from SQLite but i am able to show only last item in listview. I tried different- different solution but not getting success. 
Problem is not getting item from SQLite(I am able to fetch all item) but showing item using adapter in listview.

Here is my code.
**ListActivity.java**

```
 db=new DBHelper(getBaseContext());
 db.getWritableDatabase();
try {
final DBHelper m = new DBHelper(getBaseContext());
final List<GetSet> NotesWiseProfile = m.getBabyDetails();
for (final GetSet cn : NotesWiseProfile) {
    counter++;              
    String babyName = cn.getBabyName();
    String babyImage = cn.getBabyImage();               
    int babyId = cn.getBabyId();
    BabyData baby_data[]  = new BabyData[]
    {                       
         new BabyData(R.drawable.ic_launcher, babyName,babyId),
            };
        adapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.list_row, baby_data);
        listView1.invalidateViews();
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

**BabyData.java**

```
public class BabyData {
public int icon;
public String title;
public int babyid;
public BabyData(){
    super();
}    
public BabyData(int icon, String title,int babyId) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
    babyid = babyId;
}
```

}

**MobileArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BabyData>{

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
BabyData data[] = null;

public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, BabyData[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    DataHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new DataHolder ();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imvBabyFace);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvbabyNameList);
        holder.txtBabyId = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvBabyId);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (DataHolder )row.getTag();
    }

    BabyData weather = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
    holder.txtBabyId.setText(String.valueOf(weather.babyid));
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

    return row;
}

static class DataHolder 
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtBabyId;
}
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong in my code.  Please give me any hint or reference.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the listview declarations out of the for loop, something like:

```
BabyData baby_data[]  = new BabyData[NotesWiseProfile.size()];

for (final GetSet cn : NotesWiseProfile) {

  String babyName = cn.getBabyName();
  String babyImage = cn.getBabyImage();               
  int babyId = cn.getBabyId();
  baby_data[counter] = new BabyData(R.drawable.ic_launcher, babyName,babyId);
  counter++;    
}
adapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.list_row, baby_data);
    listView1.invalidateViews();
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: No it's not working.  it showing me error on `BabyData baby_data[]  = new BabyData[];` is `Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer` .

Comment: yep, it should be like BabyData baby_data[]  = new BabyData[NotesWiseProfile.size()];

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a field for storing you babies. Currrently, you are using a local Baby array for that. As far as I know, the ListView always gets its data from the array you passed to it (invalidating it causes the ListView to look up that data again.

To recap: Store your array as a field - if data changes, update the array and call notifyDatasetChanged() on your adapter, which will cause your ListView to reload the data.